# Cloud functions not getting invoked with serviceAccount

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts, google-cloud-tasks

I am unable to invoke cloud functions from my cloud tasks after using the service Account. I have added the function invoker roles of service account to the functions to be invoked. Also the service Account has been given service account user, cloud functions admin,cloud tasks admin and function invoker roles as well. But still not able to get the function to be invoked from the cloud tasks, no error is getting thrown but the retry count only gets incremented.

Comment: Can you paste the configuration of your Cloud Task, and how you have configured your service account on it

Comment: are you setting correctly the auth method and audience field? in this case the auth type must be  `OIDC token` and you must write the main URL of your cloud function in the audience field for example `https://us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net/myfunction`

Comment: Im setting the OidcToken. However did not set the audience since I read that if it is not set it will take the default url

Comment: with audience did you noticed any difference?

Comment: please share the task body.